# How to find the defect in this userscript for StackExchange sites?

Tags: javascript, firefox, greasemonkey, userscripts

Until a few days ago the following user script (GreaseMonkey) worked flawlessly.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        OpenID prefill
// @include     *://stackoverflow.com/users/login*
// @include     *://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/login*
// @include     *://superuser.com/users/login*
// @include     *://meta.superuser.com/users/login*
// @include     *://serverfault.com/users/login*
// @include     *://meta.serverfault.com/users/login*
// @include     *://askubuntu.com/users/login*
// @include     *://meta.askubuntu.com/users/login*
// @include     *://seasonedadvice.com/users/login*
// @include     *://meta.seasonedadvice.com/users/login*
// @include     *://crossvalidated.com/users/login*
// @include     *://askdifferent.com/users/login*
// @include     *://meta.crossvalidated.com/users/login*
// @include     *://*.stackexchange.com/users/login*
// @include     *://stackapps.com/*
// @exclude     *://chat.stackexchange.com/*
// @exclude     *://api.*.stackexchange.com/*
// @exclude     *://data.stackexchange.com/*
// @exclude     *://area51.stackexchange.com/*
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==
(function ()
{
    window.addEventListener('load', function()
    {
        document.getElementById('show-more-options').style = 'display: block;'; /* make visible */
        document.getElementById('more-options-link').style = 'display: none;'; /* hide */
        document.getElementById('openid_identifier').value = "https://my.url.tld/and/path/";
        document.getElementById('submit-button').style = 'display: none;'; /* hide */
        document.forms['login-form'].submit();
    }, false);
})();
```

The idea is this: I want to log in with OpenID. I simply want it to show the OpenID option by default, prefill the URL to my OpenID provider and then submit the form.

JavaScript is not my strongest skill, but I came up with this on my own. However, this script stopped working a few days ago.

Now I found some time to look into it and I was stomped by the fact that the IDs of the elements were still the same. So I was wondering what happened to break the script.

Even just displaying the OpenID form does no longer work, nor does hiding the "more options link".

I cannot rule out that one of the Firefox updates is the cause of the breakage either. But how would I go about to pinpoint the issue?

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can investigate using Firebug or the development tools in Chrome.
It will tell you if there is javascript error, what you are actually posting (header and body of the post) and what is the response of the server.

You can also trace the whole communication between your browser and the server and you can copy one of the messages sent by the browser and re-execute it with curl (this helps in many situations).

Answer (score 0):

The style modifications should have the style name as the property

document.getElementById('...').style.display = 'block';

Comment: Depends which way around it's modified. I think when the intent is to hide it unconditionally, the assignment of the full style as `display:none` is perfectly fine.